# Connect to webservice on my local machine from Phonegap

Tags: cordova, localhost

I am trying to use my Phonegap application to post to a database on my local machine, the problem is the connection keeps getting refused when I try to send data to my database from the Phonegap app

```
        function store()
        {

           var myJson = JSON.stringify(databaseArr);

              alert("The route to be stored is " +databaseArr);
            $.getJSON('https://127.0.0.1:5000/insert',
                {
                   data : myJson
                },
                    function(data)
                        {
                          alert("data succesfully uploaded");
                        });
                        return false;

        };
```

Here is the function I am calling to post the data, I have tried changing to the Android localhost but to no avail does anyone have a solution to this problem ? .

In my config file I have given access to any domain in the access origin tag

Comment: `127.0.0.1:5000` is an alias of `localhost` which cannot be resolved from another machine/device. You need to lookup the real IPaddress of your computer and have the device be on the same network for this to work.

Comment: I was trying that and it still wouldnt work , would the format be like this http://myipaddress:5000/insert

Comment: are your device and your computer on the same network?

Comment: Yeah they are on the same network